# Zammad Community Livechat Websocket connection not working through Synology Application Portal

Tags: websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy, synology, zammad

I have a VM on our LAN with Ubuntu 20.04 and Zammad Community installed and working. We use Synology Application Portal (Reverse-Proxy using nginx) to access it from outside and this is working too.

But a functionnality of Zammad is Livechat and uses Websockets to work and, that's the snag, Websockets doesn't work, Chat will not initialize on our main website (hosted outside).

> *Here is the **error in javascript console** on the website while loading the livechat :*
>
> [image: Zammad Livechat Synology Application Portal Websocket Issue]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to enable Websocket communication on the Synology Application Portal entry by adding some custom headers.

1. In the DSM, open the Control Panel under "Application Portal" tab
2. Select the app you want to enable Websockets
3. Go to "Custom Headers" tab
4. Add theese two entries:

   **"Upgrade"** with value **"$http_upgrade"**

   **"Connection"** with value **"$connection_upgrade"**

[image: Synology Application Portal Websockets communication rules]

> Note that, in last updates of DSM 6, a rule set has been prepared and is available under the Add button. It will create rules for you.
>
> [image: Synology Application Portal enable Websockets communication]